# Read Python list written in chars into R

Tags: python, r

I have loaded an array in R that contains, in each position, a Python list that was stored as a string, e.g. the first position of my `tmp` array is `"[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]"`.

How can I interpret the data into R to obtain a vector that, in each position, contains the said list?

Comment: Can you instead export this data as json from python? It's a waste of time and effort to invent a new interchangeable data format between r and python when json exists

Answer (score 1):

I think by far the better approach (as @Sirius suggested) is to export from python using a more portable format such as JSON.

Lacking that, if it is always python lists and tuples, then you can `gsub` the `()` to `[]` and parse it as json:

```r
tr <- function(x, from="()", to="[]") {
  chrs <- Map(c, strsplit(from, "")[[1]], strsplit(to, "")[[1]])
  Reduce(function(txt, chr) gsub(chr[1], chr[2], txt, fixed = TRUE), chrs, init = x)
}

tr("[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]")
# [1] "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]"

jsonlite::parse_json(tr("[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]"))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 2
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 3
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 4
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] 5
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] 6
```

The `tr` function works with vectors of strings as well:

```r
tr(c("[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]", "[(1,2),(3,4),(5,7)]"))
# [1] "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]" "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,7]]"
```

but to use `jsonlite::` for this, you will need `stream_in` instead, since technically it'll be ndjson (`n`ewline-`d`elimited), plus controlling simplification:

```r
vec <- c("[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]", "[(1,2),(3,4),(5,7)]")
tr(vec)
# [1] "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]" "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,7]]"
out <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(tr(vec)), simplifyVector = FALSE)
#  Imported 2 records. Simplifying...
str(out)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 1
#   .. ..$ : int 2
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 3
#   .. ..$ : int 4
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 5
#   .. ..$ : int 6
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 1
#   .. ..$ : int 2
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 3
#   .. ..$ : int 4
#   ..$ :List of 2
#   .. ..$ : int 5
#   .. ..$ : int 7
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a nested `list` in `R`.  An option is `reticulate`

```
library(reticulate)
tmp <- "[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]"
py_run_string(paste0('out=', tmp))$out
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 2


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 4


#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] 6
```